# What is the time complexity of this agorithm (that solves leetcode question 650) (question 2)?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

Hello I have been working on https://leetcode.com/problems/2-keys-keyboard/ and came upon this dynamic programming question.

You start with an 'A' on a blank page and you get a number n when you are done you should have n times 'A' on the page. The catch is you are allowed only 2 operations copy (and you can only copy the total amount of A's currently on the page) and paste --> find the minimum number of operations to get n 'A' on the page.

I solved this problem but then found a better solution in the discussion section of leetcode --> and I can't figure out it's time complexity.

```
    def minSteps(self, n):
        factors = 0
        i=2
        while i <= n:
            while n % i == 0:
                factors += i
                n /= i
            i+=1
        return factors
```

The way this works is `i` is never gonna be bigger than the biggest prime factor `p` of `n` so the outer loop is `O(p)` and the inner while loop is basically `O(logn)` since we are dividing `n /= i` at each iteration.

But the way I look at it we are doing `O(logn)` divisions in total for the inner loop while the outer loop is `O(p)` so using aggregate analysis this function is basically `O(max(p, logn))` is this correct ?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Yes ! You are absolutely right.

Comment: Hmm, but the `i` loop always goes to the original n+1 -- it doesn't matter if n changes. I think the code should replace the `for` loop with `i=2; while i <= n: ... i+=1`

Comment: oops you are absolutely right Paul thanks for noticing. This algo is basically O(n) then ...

Comment: What is `p`? Did you mean `n`'?

Comment: Hello Jim sorry for the delay, no I meant `p` with p being the biggest prime factor of `n`. You are right it does not make sense with the code as is I am gonna modify it as per Paul Hankin's comment.

Comment: Basically with this modified version you can see that `i` will never be bigger than the largest prime factor of `n` since we are dividing `n` by `i` as soon as `i` is a factor of `n` --> ` while n % i == 0`

Comment: So `i` can never get to `n` unless `n` is a prime number like 7, 11 etc ... I recommend running a couple examples and you will get it quickly

Comment: It is odd to express the complexity in terms of *p* when that is not the input (but derived from it). Your input is only *n*, so it makes sense to express the complexity in terms of *n* alone.

Comment: for a prime  it will be O(n). You souldnt do i+=1 cause if you have found one factor you can skip digits what divides on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct: *O(max(p, logn))* gives the time complexity, assuming that arithmetic operations take constant time. This assumption is not true for arbitrary large *n*, that would not fit in the machine's fixed-size number storage, and where you would need Big-Integer operations that have [non-constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Arithmetic_functions) time complexity. But I will ignore that.

It is still odd to express the complexity in terms of *p* when that is not the input (but derived from it). Your input is only *n*, so it makes sense to express the complexity in terms of *n* alone.

### Worst Case

Clearly, when *n* is prime, the algorithm is *O(n)* -- the inner loop never iterates.

For a prime *n*, the algorithm will take more time than for *n+1*, as even the smallest factor of *n+1* (i.e. 2), will halve the number of iterations of the outer loop, and yet only add 1 block of constant work in the inner loop.

So *O(n)* is the worst case.

### Average Case

For the average case, we note that the division of *n* happens just as many times as *n* has prime factors (counting duplicates). For example, for *n = 12*, we have 3 divisions, as *n = 2·2·3*

The [average number of prime factors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactor.html) for *1 < n < x* approaches *loglogn + B*, where *B* is some constant. So we could say the *average* time complexity for the total execution of the inner loop is *O(loglogn)*.

We need to add to that the execution of the outer loop. This corresponds to the average *greatest* prime factor. For *1 < n < x* [this average approaches *C.n/logn*](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n81/n81.pdf), and so we have:

*O(n/logn + loglogn)*

Now *n/logn* is the more important term here, so this simplifies to:

*O(n/logn)*